# Configure Pointcut for Spring JPA repository methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I am trying to create an Aspect which runs after every call to save() of Spring JpaRepository. I have defined my Aspect as follows:

```
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterReturning;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
@Slf4j
public class ProcessAspect {

    @Autowired
    private ProcessService processService;

    @AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com.domain.control.repository.ProcessDao.save())))",
    returning = "result")
    private void propagateProcess(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
        log.info("Aspect is working, congratulations. Jointpoint {} , result {}", joinPoint, result.toString());
        Process process = (process) result;

       // do something on the object returned by save()
        processService.createOrUpdateProcess(process);
    }

}
```

My repository is defined as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface ProcessDao extends JpaRepository<Process, String>
```

If I configure it this way then the aspect is not working.

How can I configure my aspect to run after generic JPA repository methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First your `ProcessDao` doesn't have a `save` method, so it won't match, secondly you have a pointcut with a no-args `save` method and there is no such thing. Instead you want to use one of the Spring Data repository classes in your pointcut and match 1 argument.

Something like this

```
execution(* org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository+.save(..))))
```

or to make it more generic

```
execution(* org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository+.save(..))))
```

This should make your pointcut match. There is also a `saveAll` and `saveAndFlush` so you might want to add a few more pointcuts if you need to intercept those as well.

Comment: I tried adding the save method  in ProcessDao along with adding arguments in save Pointcut. It didn't work but the regex I used was different, I will try with this regex now.

Comment: It isn't a regexp but a pointcut expression written in the AspectJ pointcut language. Also instead of * yuo might want to use .. (meaning 0 or more parameters).

Comment: The Pointcut expression is working, and I didn't add save method in ProcessDao as well. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: A follow up on this, the JPARepository has save() which can take a list as well as a single object. How can I implement two different pointcut expressions for these cases?

Comment: Which is a different question, which I'm not attempting to answer in a comment as there are several ways.

Comment: @RamanPreetSingh Have you found what you asked? Would you please share if you have? Thanks.

Comment: @JinKwon the answer posted above answered my question.